# Заголовки категорий в Wordpress перед списком статей

Tags: php, wordpress

Предположим есть такой код:

```
$args = array(
    'post-type'     => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'meta_key'      => 'cat',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
    'order'         => 'ASC'
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post); 
        echo "<div>";
        echo the_title();
        echo the_content();
        echo "</div>"
    }
}
```

Он выводит посты и сортирует их по значению поля `"cat"`. Это поле относится к постам определённой категории. Т.е. у каждой категории своё значение. Получается что сначала выводятся посты одной категории, потом другой, и т.д.
Как сделать, чтобы перед постами каждой категории выводился заголовок этой категории?

Comment: Что такое значение поля "cat"? Это "мета"? Просто в запросе в приведенном коде у нее ключ "321"
Вообще вопрос несколько не стыкуется с кодом. У вас в коде сортировка по мете, а вы пишете про "посты одной категории, потом другой..."

Comment: да, косякнул. это название мета-поля. просто на ходу писал и скопировал '321' это 'cat'. сортировка по мете, у постов каждой категории своё мета поле. т.е например у всех постов категории "Булки" это поле например 1. у постов категории "Бубубу" оно 2. При выводе они сортируются. Сначала посты с метой 1, потом с метой 2. И вот перед всеми постами с метой 1 - название "Булки". перед всеми постами с метой 2 - "Бубубу".

Comment: Старайтесь существенные изменения выносить в вопрос, а в комментарии просто указать, например "дополнил вопрос"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ...
    $lastCat = FALSE;
    foreach ($attachments as $post) {
        // Берем ID категории из меты поста
        $cat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cat');
        // Если категория поменялась
        if ($lastCat !== $cat) {
            // Берем наименование категории
            $categoryName = get_cat_name($cat); 
            // Выводим в браузер (не забывая экранировать)
            echo '<h2>' . esc_html($categoryName) . '</h2>';
            // Запоминаем измененную категорию
            $lastCat = $cat;
        }
        setup_postdata($post); 
        echo "<div>";
        echo the_title();
        echo the_content();
        echo "</div>"
    }
// ...
```

Comment: хорошо, а как быть с сортировкой постов внутри полученных категорий? мы уже указали `order_by => meta_value`, но это действует только для категорий в данном примере. перед массивом как раз указывали. а посты внутри категории сортируются автоматически по дате от ранних к поздним, а нужно наоборот. Это, я так полагаю отдельно делать на js или php?

Comment: Начиная с WP4.0 можно указывать несколько полей сортировки `'orderby' => array('meta_value' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC')`